# Access Expression Building Reference to itself

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, expressionbuilder

Lets say I have a report that has two columns; "Commission" & "Commission Cancallation".  In my report these are represented as textboxes; txtC and txtCC.  I want to txtC to be $0, if txtCC is not null.  I so I tried the following in `Expression Builder IIF(ISNULL([txtCC]), [txtCC], 0)` but this give me a Reference to itself error.  I get the circular problem of assign value to oneself, but I have figured out a method to resolve my problem.  I sure smarter people than I have resolve this, so I am calling out to the smart people.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure to rename the textbox to something else before you made this change?

```
 =IIF(ISNULL([txtCC]), [txtCC], 0)
```

Should be fine in a textbox called say, `atextbox`.

Comment: So using this express in the Control Source of the TextBox txtC.  It need to be able to set the value of txtC to 0 if txtCC is not null.